# C# compare fields from different lines in csv

Tags: c#, csv, textfieldparser

I am trying to compare the value in the 0 index of an array on one line and the 0 index on the following line. Imagine a CSV where I have a unique identifier in the first column, a corresponding value in the second column.

```
USER1, 1P
USER1, 3G
USER2, 1P
USER3, 1V
```

I would like to check the value of [0] the next line (or previous if that's easier) to compare and if they are the same (as they are in the example) concatenate it to index 1. That is, the data should read as

```
USER1, 1P, 3G
USER2, 1P
USER3, 1V
```

before it gets passed onto the next function. So far I have

```
 private void csvParse(string path)
        {
            using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(path))
                {
                    parser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
                    while (!parser.EndOfData)
                    {
                        string[] parts = parser.ReadFields();
                        if (parts == null)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        contact.ContactId = parts[0];
                        long nextLine;
                        nextLine = parser.LineNumber+1;
//if line1 parts[0] == line2 parts[0] etc.
                    }
                }
            }
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: What would the output be if you had a line at the end `USER1, 1X`?

Comment: @Eser the report that's generated is written in a way that all identical unique identifiers are all written in succession. That is, if USER1 appeared, it would appear all in one area, not randomly throughout the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about saving the array into a variable:

```
private void csvParse(string path)
        {
            using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(path))
                {
                    parser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
                    string[] oldParts = new string[] { string.Empty };
                    while (!parser.EndOfData)
                    {
                        string[] parts = parser.ReadFields();
                        if (parts == null || parts.Length < 1)
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                        if (oldParts[0] == parts[0])
                        {
                             // concat logic goes here
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            contact.ContactId = parts[0];
                        }

                        long nextLine;
                        nextLine = parser.LineNumber+1;
                        oldParts = parts;
//if line1 parts[0] == line2 parts[0] etc.
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: This solution worked and required the least amount of work to implement. parts[0] compared to oldParts[0] and if they're the same, parts[1] was concatenated to oldParts[1] to be sent to the next function.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, what you are asking is essentially "how do I group the values in the second column based on the values in the first column?".

A quick and quite succinct way of doing this would be to [Group By using LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx):

```
var linesGroupedByUser =
    from line in File.ReadAllLines(path)
    let elements = line.Split(',')
    let user = new {Name = elements[0], Value = elements[1]}
    group  user by user.Name into users
    select users;

foreach (var user in linesGroupedByUser)
{
    string valuesAsString = String.Join(",", user.Select(x => x.Value));

    Console.WriteLine(user.Key + ", " + valuesAsString);
}
```

I have left out the use of your `TextFieldParser` class, but you can easily use that instead. This approach does, however, require that you can afford to load all of the data into memory. You don't mention whether this is viable.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do something like this is to convert each line to an object. You can use `CsvHelper`, https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/, to do the work for you or you can iterate each line and parse to an object. It is a great tool and it knows how to properly parse CSV files into a collection of objects. Then, whether you create the collection yourself or use `CsvHelper`, you can use `Linq` to `GroupBy`, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.100).aspx,  your "key" (in this case UserId) and `Aggregate`, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218(v=vs.110).aspx, the other property into a string. Then, you can use the new, grouped by, collection for your end goal (write it to file or use it for whatever you need).

Answer (score 0):

You're basically finding all the unique entries so put them into a dictionary with the contact id as the key.  As follows:

```
 private void csvParse(string path)
    {
        using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(path))
        {
            parser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> uniqueContacts = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] parts = parser.ReadFields();
                if (parts == null || parts.Count() != 2)
                {
                    break;
                }
                //if contact id not present in dictionary add
                if (!uniqueContacts.ContainsKey(parts[0]))
                    uniqueContacts.Add(parts[0],new List<string>());
                //now there's definitely an existing contact in dic (the one 
                //we've just added or a previously added one) so add to the                   
                //list of strings for that contact
                uniqueContacts[parts[0]].Add(parts[1]);
            }

            //now do something with that dictionary of unique user names and
            // lists of strings, for example dump them to console in the 
            //format you specify:

            foreach (var contactId in uniqueContacts.Keys)
            {

                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append($"contactId, ");
                foreach (var bit in uniqueContacts[contactId])
                {
                    sb.Append(bit);
                    if (bit != uniqueContacts[contactId].Last())
                        sb.Append(", ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine(sb);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Rather than just marking down, please tell me what is wrong with this idea